# Options popup do not appear for the extension

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

i am building a thunderbird extension and enabled the options popup by adding following to the install.rdf

```
 <em:optionsURL>chrome://content/options.xul</em:optionsURL>
```

this enables the button but on clicking it nothing happens. the options.xul looks like as below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<prefwindow id="EmailToOSN-prefs"
     title="StockWatcher 2 Options"
     xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

<prefpane id="sw2-stock-pane" label="Stock Settings">
  <preferences>
    <preference id="pref_symbol" name="extensions.stockwatcher2.symbol" type="string"/>
  </preferences>

  <hbox align="center">
    <label control="symbol" value="Stock to watch: "/>
    <textbox preference="pref_symbol" id="symbol" maxlength="4"/>
  </hbox>
</prefpane>

</prefwindow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a folder `content` where you have placed your code files
(including `options.xul`)

1. First you have to declare this "content" folder in your
   `chrome.manifest` file by adding this line:

   ```
   content extension_name content/
   ```
2. Second in your `install.rdf` file you must write this:

   ```
   <em:optionsURL>chrome://extension_name/content/options.xul</em:optionsURL>
   ```
3. Third add this line in your `options.xul` file inside the `prefwindow` tab:

   ```
   <script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://extension_name/content/options.js" />
   ```

   where `options.js` will be your javascript code you will use for
   this options window

Hope I helped...